# JQuery Ajax Success Handler unable to find class function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a js Class that posts some data. However, when the success handler is fired, it is unable to find the function. When the class is constructed, the function is found. I can call it from any other function. It just doesn't seem to be able to find it -- in the success handler.

**How do I get the success handler to be able to see other functions in the class?**

I get the error:

> TypeError: this.doSomething is not a function

```
class MyClass {

    constructor(options) {
        this.doSomething();

        $("#btn_submit").on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            post({});
        });
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log('Doing Something');
    }

    successHandler(data) {
       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       // THIS IS WHERE IT CAN"T FIND THE FUNCTION
       // And the error is thrown
       this.doSomething();
    }

    errorHandler() {
       console.log('An error occurred);
    }


    post(data) {
        $.ajax({
           url        : 'some post url',
           type       : 'POST',
           data       : data,
           contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           dataType   : 'json',
           success    : successHandler,
           error      : errorHandler
       });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've lost the context. Add `.bind(this)` to `successHandler/errorHandler`.

```js
    post(data) {
        $.ajax({
           url        : 'some post url',
           type       : 'POST',
           data       : data,
           contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           dataType   : 'json',
           success    : this.successHandler.bind(this),
           error      : this.errorHandler.bind(this)
       });
    }
```

Further reading: https://towardsdatascience.com/javascript-context-this-keyword-9a78a19d5786

Comment: That is it. When the time expires I'll accept the answer.